# iOS 7 MPMusicPlayer volume Property deprecated

Tags: ios, volume, ipod

In iOS 7 the MPMusicPlayer player 'volume' property is deprecated.

My app programatically changes the volume of an application generated iPod player. What is the correct method of changing the volume of the iPod player that does not generate any warning messages?

Comment: Your question has already been [asked and answered here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no), Phil.