# iOS7 MPMusicPlayerController Music Fade-In/Fade-Out Effect

Tags: ios7, fade, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I've been using **MPMusicPlayerController** to play Music within the app, which has no volume slider available to the user.

There are instances that I have to fade the music in and out.  So far I've been using **volume** property from **MPMusicPlayerController** within a loop to do that.

After iOS7, **volume** property is deprecated.  Apple wants devs to use **MPVolumeView**.  I have no use with a volume slider, just need to fade the music at certain occasions.  Is there a way with iOS7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to move to AVPlayer if you need control of fades. It is a bit more complex but will do what you need.

Comment: You can hide the slider, change its value, and fake a touchUp event. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no