# how to Control iOS system Volume using a UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a music player app and I wanna control system volume through a UISlider How can I do it? I've searched google and stack overflow but its showing something related to `MPMusicPlayerController` and `MPVolumeView` and that too not easy to understand. Is there any API for It. please do help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love new learners... Simple answer for you...

First create a `UIView` in your StoryBoard, where you want to put a volume slider.
Now create a `IBOutlet` for that view in your ViewController implementation.

for ex:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView* volumeView;
```

Now in the `viewDidLoad` method write the following code:

```
MPVolumeView *mpVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc]initWithFrame:self.volumeView.bounds];
[self.volumeView addSubview:mpVolumeView];
[mpVolumeView sizeToFit];
```

Now you will have volume control in your app...

**Note: this code will not work for a simulator.**

cheers.

Answer (score 2):

No API's required at all.

If you're a beginner, you should go through [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/) from the Apple Documentation. Everything is given there in detail. Just have a look at it.

**It says:**

> Use a volume view to present the user with a slider control for
>   setting the system audio output volume, and a button for choosing the
>   audio output route. When first displayed, the slider’s position
>   reflects the current system audio output volume. As the user drags the
>   slider, the changes update the volume. If the user presses the device
>   volume buttons while sound is playing, the slider moves to reflect the
>   new volume.

Answer (score 1):

No API is needed. That's the whole point. MPVolumeView just works. It is a slider that controls system volume.  Make one, stick it in the interface, done.

Answer (score 1):

MPVolume view should do the job. Here are couple of examples:

[iOS 7: MPMusicPlayerController volume deprecated. How to change device volume now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/

but if you need custom interface:

```
 // Set the value of slider to system volume control
 [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] setVolume:self.mySlider.value];
```

possibly you also need to use this:

```
 // Set it somewhere in your code
 [self.moviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:YES]; // this generates a depreciation warning
```