# Cordova / Phonegap Control device volume through app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

i'm developing an app using cordova and ionic.
This app will be used as alert security system, so if the user unplug the lightning cable from the phone, an alert sound will fire.

The problem: If the user set the phone to silent/vibe, the sound will not play;

So, what i need to know is, with cordova, is there a way i can:

1- Disable volume buttons, so the user can't change and set to silent/vibe?
2- Control the device volume (IOS/Android), so when the cable is off, the volume will be max and the sound will play?

Thanks guys!

**EDIT**

The link sent is not working, missing documentation is complicated to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: is therey anyway to volume control by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322218/android-is-therey-anyway-to-volume-control-by-javascript)

Comment: @Hitesh Sahu, this plugs seems not to work, or because there's not an good documentation i don't know how to implement it, i'm installing, se it on my app, and then it returns this error: require is not defined at VolumeSlider.js

Comment: @WilliamXavier, did you find a solution?

Comment: Bump!  This would be huge and I can't believe there isn't an elegant way to handle this.